# Is rustic camping available along any of Michigan's cyling trails?

Tags: camping, united-states, wild-camping, biking

Among all of the cycling friendly trails in Michigan, do any of them offer the opportunity for rustic or dispersed camping? Preferably, every 20 to 40 miles or so.

Comment: This question belongs on Outdoors.SE most likely -- its more of a camping question than a bicycle question.

Comment: What exactly is *rustic or dispersed camping*?

Comment: @Liam "rustic" and "primitive" are typically used for campsites without running water and electricity. "Dispersed" or "backcountry" camping means you can camp anywhere (in accordance with any local regulations, favoring spots with existing fire rings, etc.)

Comment: I can only offer one small bit: http://www.vbco.org/trail_camping.asp.  A couple campgrounds along the western section of the Kal-Haven.  Sounds  like these are a bit "developed" for your taste though.

Comment: thanks for clarifying @whrrgarbl. These are not common terms where I come from (the UK)

Answer (score 2):

In the U.P. [(Upper Peninsula of Michigan)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_Peninsula_of_Michigan), there are several long gravel trails (primarily ATV/snowmobile, but also allow cycling) that pass through Hiawatha and Ottawa National Forests, both of which allow dispersed camping.

Comment: What's the U.P.?

Comment: U.P. = "Upper Peninsula" (portion of Michigan). 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_Peninsula_of_Michigan

Comment: Hi Matt! I hope you don't mind, I put the location text from your comment into the post so people can see it right away.